# inter process communication - Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, ipc

Currently I am building apps for iOS and Android. On both platforms I try to achieve the same:

- SearchApp - The user can fill in the search term in a text box.
- BackgroundApp - running in background. This background app processes the search requests from the user.

In android it is possible to make use of a Service. But on iOS I haven't found a proper way of getting this done. It also needs to work if the mobile phone is not connected to internet.

So I am looking for a proper way which works on iOS and Android. What is the best way to achieve inter process communication:

- Is there a WebSocket approach? does this also work when the mobile phone is offline?
- [AppLinks](http://applinks.org/)? Is this only for redirecting or also to request data from another app?
- Is 'WCF like' approach available on both platforms?
- Other?

If possible, please provide examples.

Comment: Why would you split this into two apps?  This will be particularly problematic on iOS

Comment: @Paulw11. This example is a subtraction of the real situation. The real situation is that both apps already exists for several years and now these two apps should be able to work together

Comment: Inter process communication isn't really available on iOS because only one app can be in the foreground at any point in time. voip apps can listen to sockets in the background but there is no general purpose network server background mode available.